# Name bars in highcharts bar chart by data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the highcharts library, and I am attempting to create a bar chart however I am having problems in regards to naming the 'bars' in the chart. By default, they shows their numerical value (0, 1, 2 and so on), however I would like to name them by the data passed to the series.
The data is passed in an array such as: `['yahoo.com', 1700],`, and the name displays correctly on hover, how can I also display it where the numerical index currently is?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bpwsadu/1/
Thanks

Comment: By Default highcharts takes numbers for xAxis lables, if you want your own names, there is a provision with categories. Here in your example you are naming them from series data. But you are not telling it to make the labels null. so make `categories: []` to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your code ([categories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories))

```
xAxis: {
  categories: []
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3bpwsadu/2/

Answer (score 3):

The categories arrays is not required, only what you need is set `type as category.`

http://jsfiddle.net/3bpwsadu/3/